# A set $S$ of a topological space $(X,T)$ is a perfect set iff it's closed and has no isolated points

Tags: general-topology

A set $S$ of a topological space $(X,T)$ is a perfect set iff it's closed and has no isolated points.

I've proven this $\Rightarrow$'s, but $\Leftarrow$'s I'm stuck with.  I'm trying to prove that if $x \in S \Rightarrow x \in S'$.  I'm given that $S$ is closed and there are no isolated points.  So my goal is to prove that $x$ is a limit point of S.  Therefore I have to prove: $$(\forall U \in T)(x \in U)(\exists y \in U \cap S)(y \neq x)$$  I know that no singleton point is $S$ is open because of the lack of isolated points, so any open set in $S$ must have $>1$ points but from here I can't figure out any links.

I'm working with the definition of a perfect set as: $S = S'$.

Comment: What's your definition of closed sets? Do you know $C$ closed iff $C' \subseteq C$?

Comment: An isolated point of $S$ is just an open set of $S$ with one point.

Comment: When it says "has no isolated points", is that saying that if $x$ is an isolated point of $(X,T) \Rightarrow x \notin S$ ? Or is it saying that the subspace induced on $(S,T_S)$ has no isolated points?

Comment: The latter. $S$ as a subspace has no isolated points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from two basic facts:

1. A set is closed iff $S' \subseteq S$.

This should be well-known, and in some books this is even the definition of closed sets.

2. A set has no isolated points iff $S \subseteq S'$.

Left to right: suppose $x \in S$, and let $O$ be open with $x \in O$. Then $O \cap S \neq \{x\}$ because otherwise $x$ would be an isolated point of $S$ (i.e. $\{x\}$ would be open in the subspace topology on $S$). Hence $x \in S'$ as $O$ is arbitrary.

Right to left: Assume $S \subseteq S'$ and let $x \in S$. Suppose $x$ were an isolated point of $S$, then $\{x\}$ is open in $S$, so there exists $O$ open in $X$ such that $O \cap S = \{x\}$. But then $x \in O$ and $O \cap (S \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$, contradicting that $x \in S'$.